# "No Tests were found" in Pycharm Professional 2019.1 using Behave

Tags: python, pycharm, bdd

Starting Python BDD, using Behave in pycharm 2019.1 pro. Just started learning Python and Pycharm IDE.

Used a basic example to run a feature file with one scenario in it.
When I run using Pycharm Terminal, the scenario runs fine. When I do the same while right clicking on the Scenario in the editor, I get the message at run time, "No tests were found".

I have searched on SO but responses are for unit tests not for BDD tests.

I went into the run/debug configuration and have tried setup working directory to my feature folder or the project folder, but still the same issue.

I previously had python 3.7 but now using python 3.6 (both installed) and the interpreter is set to behave

Answer (score 0):

I got it working but uninstalling pycharm, python 3.6 and python 3.7 folders completely (includuing hidden folders from private @ root) from my machine, fresh install pycharm with python 3.6 and then behave. Tests work now.

No idea exactly why it happened except that it could be some conflicting config due to different python versions.

Answer (score 0):

Right clicking on any Scenario to run/debug it suddenly started saying
"No tests found". Traced it to the Background clause that had no steps (example below). Remove or comment this out and everything
worked again.

(PyCharm 2021.2.1 Professional Edition)

```
Background: Kiosk created and configured and assigned a Criteria Group

  Scenario: A Kiosk can be created by Admin
```